# Who rewrites redis configuration slaveof of slave redis instances?

Tags: redis-sentinel

Consider a redis sentinel setup with 5 machines. Each machine has sentinel process(s1,s2,s3,s4,s5) and redis instance(r1,r2,r3,r4,r5) running. One is master(r1) and others as slave(r2...r5). During failover of master r1, redis configuration slaveof of must be override with new master r3.

Who will override the redis configuration of slave redis(r2,r4,r5)? Elected sentinel responsible for failover(assuming s2 is elected sentinel) s2 will override the redis configuration at r2,r4,r5 or sentinel running at their respective machine will override the local redis configuration(sn will override configuration of rn)?

Answer (score 1):

**Elected Sentinel** would update the configuration.This is the full list of Sentinel capabilities at a high level:

**Monitoring**: Sentinel constantly checks if your master and slave instances are working as expected.

**Notification**: Sentinel can notify the system administrator, another computer programs, via an API, that something is wrong with one of the monitored Redis instances.

**Automatic failover**: If a master is not working as expected, Sentinel can start a failover process where a slave is promoted to master, the other additional slaves are reconfigured to use the new master, and the applications using the Redis server informed about the new address to use when connecting.

**Configuration provider**: Sentinel acts as a source of authority for clients service discovery: clients connect to Sentinels in order to ask for the address of the current Redis master responsible for a given service. If a failover occurs, Sentinels will report the new address.

For more details, refer to [docs](https://redis.io/topics/sentinel)